# Understanding a characterization of minimal sufficient statistics

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, sufficient-statistics

I have some questions regarding the proof of the theorem below.

First we need a definition:

> A statistic $T$ is minimal sufficient iff $T$ is a function of any other sufficient statistic.

That is, for any sufficient statistic $S$ there exists a function $H$ such that $T=H(S)$.

Also consider this:

> Let $\mathcal{K}$  be the set of all pairs $(\boldsymbol{x,y})$ for which there is a $k(\boldsymbol{x,y})>0$ such that $L(\theta;\boldsymbol{x}) = k(\boldsymbol{x,y})L(\theta;\boldsymbol{y})$.

#### Theorem

> Let $T$ be a sufficient statistic for $\mathcal{P} = \{P_{\theta}:\theta \in \Theta \} $. If for all $(\boldsymbol{x,y}) \in \mathcal{K}, T(\boldsymbol{x}) =T(\boldsymbol{y}) $, then $T$ is minimal sufficient.

#### The Proof

Let $S$ be an arbitrary sufficient statistic and the pair $(\boldsymbol{x,y})$ such that $S(\boldsymbol{x}) =S(\boldsymbol{y}) $. By the factorization criterion we have:

\begin{equation}L(\theta; \boldsymbol{x}) = g(S(\boldsymbol{x});\theta)h(\boldsymbol{x}) \quad and \quad L(\theta; \boldsymbol{y})=g(S(\boldsymbol{y});\theta)h(\boldsymbol{y})  \end{equation}
and therefore

\begin{equation}L(\theta;\boldsymbol{x}) = \dfrac{h(\boldsymbol{x})}{h(\boldsymbol{y})}L(\theta;\boldsymbol{y}) \end{equation}

Thus $(\boldsymbol{x,y}) \in \mathcal{K}$ and  $T(\boldsymbol{y}) = T(\boldsymbol{x})$. But this means $T$ is a function of $S$.

#### Question

How does one see that $T$ is a function of $S$ in the proof?

Also, why are they imposing a restriction $S(\boldsymbol{x}) = S(\boldsymbol{y})$ in the proof? what if  $S(\boldsymbol{x}) \neq S(\boldsymbol{y})$?

Answer (score 5):

The symbols $\boldsymbol{x,y}$ refer to *data*.  Associated with each possible value $v$ of the statistic $S$ is a collection of possible data values $S^{-1}(v)$ for which $S$ has the value $v$.  Since $T$ has the same value (call it $w$) on every such dataset, we may define $H(v) = w$.

The case $S(\boldsymbol{x}) \ne S(\boldsymbol{y})$ is irrelevant to the theorem.

---

**Let's interpret the theorem.**  Say that two datasets $\boldsymbol{x,y}$ are *equivalent* if the *relative likelihood function*

$$\theta \to \frac{L(\theta,\boldsymbol{x})}{L(\theta,\boldsymbol{y})}$$

is constant.  This means that any analysis based on comparing likelihoods (for different values of $\theta$) will not make any distinction between any two equivalent datasets.  The theorem informs us that **a minimal sufficient statistic will not ever distinguish between two equivalent datasets** (that is, it must have the same value on each).

The proof of the theorem proceeds by noting that any two datasets having the same value of $S$ must be equivalent (provided that $S$ is sufficient) and therefore $T$ will have the same value on those datasets.

We might picture this by supposing that this equivalence relation among datasets partitions $\Omega$ into separate, overlapping components, each being a collection of equivalent datasets.  Sufficient statistics have different values on different components: this guarantees that they can discriminate among *inequivalent* datasets.  However, their values within any given component might vary (thereby discriminating among some equivalent datasets, too).  Any *minimal* sufficient statistic, though, will be constant on each component: it will not discriminate between two equivalent datasets.

---

The following is a formal mathematical demonstration that $T$ is a function of $S$.

Let the set of all possible such data be $\Omega$.  A *statistic*, such as $S$ or $T$, assigns some kind of mathematical object  to each dataset $\boldsymbol{x}\in\Omega$--such as a number or vector--that we can calculate with.  The details don't matter, so suppose $S$ assigns objects in a set $V$ and $T$ assigns objects in a set $W$.  If the function $H$ exists, then it is a map from $V$ to $W$ (depending on $S$, by the way):

$$\begin{array}{rrcll}
           \;   &&\Omega  \\
           \; &^S\swarrow & &\searrow^T  \\
           \; V & &\xrightarrow{H} &&W \\
\end{array}$$

Given $T$ and $S$ as in the question, what we know is that

> For all $\boldsymbol{x,y}\in\Omega$, $S(\boldsymbol{x}) = S(\boldsymbol{y})$ implies $T(\boldsymbol{x}) = T(\boldsymbol{y})$.

From this we would like to deduce the existence of a function $H:V\to W$ such that $T = H\circ S$: that is, $T(\boldsymbol{x}) = H(S(\boldsymbol{x}))$ for all $\boldsymbol{x}\in\Omega$.

**$H$ can be found with an explicit construction.**  One way begins with a function $H^{*}$ defined on $V$ whose values are *subsets* of $W$ defined as

$$H^{*}(v) = T(S^{-1}(v)) = \{T(\boldsymbol{x})\,|\, S(\boldsymbol{x}) = v\}.$$

I claim that all elements of $H^{*}(v)$ are equal, no matter what $v\in V$ might be.  To prove the claim let $u, w\in H^{*}(v)$.  By definition, this means there are $\boldsymbol{x,y}\in\Omega$ such that $u=T(\boldsymbol{x})$ and $w=T(\boldsymbol{y})$ and $S(\boldsymbol{x}) = S(\boldsymbol{y}) = v$.  The latter equality implies $u = T(\boldsymbol{x}) = T(\boldsymbol{y}) = w$, proving the claim.

This claim enables us to define $H(v)$ whenever $H^{*}(v)$ is nonempty: it's the *unique* element of $H^{*}(v)$.  To complete the definition of $H$, pick an arbitrary $w_0\in W$ and set $H(v) = w_0$ when $H(v)$ is empty.  Formally,

$$H(v) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         w & \text{if } H^{*}(v) = \{w\}\\
        w_0 & \text{if } H^{*}(v) = \emptyset.
\end{array} \right. $$